# laptop takes 1+ minute to boot even before the HP logo splash screen

Tags: boot, drivers, partitioning, 20.04, bios

The laptop takes 1+ minute to boot even before the HP splash screen loads, after the HP screen it takes only a few seconds however. The whole process took around 10 secs on windows. I have been a Ubuntu user for 3+ years now but this the first time installing it on a laptop and on an amd machine.

Here is the `systemd-analyze blame` output, it doesn’t explain how it takes 1+ minute though:

```
6.590s NetworkManager-wait-online.service                   
5.987s dev-sda2.device                                      
5.159s plymouth-quit-wait.service                           
2.449s snapd.service                                        
 850ms networkd-dispatcher.service                          
 849ms dev-loop8.device                                     
 801ms dev-loop4.device                                     
 780ms dev-loop3.device                                     
 775ms dev-loop5.device                                     
 753ms dev-loop6.device                                     
 740ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d38\x2d2004-87.mount               
 739ms dev-loop7.device                                     
 735ms fwupd.service                                        
 734ms dev-loop9.device                                     
 707ms dev-loop10.device                                    
 647ms dev-loop11.device                                    
 631ms lm-sensors.service                                   
 608ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1515.mount              
 587ms dev-loop12.device[enter image description here][1]
```

there is a photo of the screen where it stops:

[image: the screen where it stops]

Here are my specs-

1. ram: 4gb
2. storage: crucial bx500 250 gb
3. processor: amd a10 9600p with integrated amd a5 graphics.
4. dedicated graphics: amd a7 m340
5. display: 1366x768

The laptop also cannot wake up after being suspended(could both problems be related somehow), the amd drivers are upto date and the proprietary drivers can't be installed.

the disk partition is shown below as well

[image: disk management]

---

**edit 1:** `systemd-analyze critical-chain` results:

```
graphical.target @21.797s
└─multi-user.target @21.796s
  └─virtualbox.service @21.687s +107ms
    └─network-online.target @21.680s
      └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @15.029s +6.649s
        └─NetworkManager.service @14.751s +273ms
          └─dbus.service @14.746s
            └─basic.target @14.726s
              └─sockets.target @14.726s
                └─snapd.socket @14.724s +1ms
                  └─sysinit.target @14.717s
                    └─snapd.apparmor.service @14.589s +127ms
                      └─apparmor.service @14.427s +160ms
                        └─local-fs.target @14.425s
                          └─boot-efi.mount @14.406s +18ms
                            └─systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-0B73\x2d388C.service @14.361s +42ms
                              └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-0B73\x2d388C.device @14.351s
```

---

**edit 2:** `systemd-analyze time` results:

```
Startup finished in 4.286s (firmware) + 1min 1.281s (loader) + 2.513s (kernel) + 12.800s (userspace) = 1min 20.881s 
graphical.target reached after 12.452s in userspace
```

---

**edit 3:** entered bios and disabled legacy boot and here are the systemd analyze time results now:

```
Startup finished in 3.191s (firmware) + 4.930s (loader) + 2.713s (kernel) + 12.144s (userspace) = 22.979s 
graphical.target reached after 11.743s in userspace
```

so the bootup time was cut in half

Comment: disk partition- https://i.stack.imgur.co/szDfM.jpg
  ------------------------------------------------------------- ----------------                                                                                      screen where it stops-                 https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2UJI.jpg

Comment: Please edit and post the output of `systemd-analyze critical-chain`.

Comment: i posted those, my desktop also has 20.04 and boots in a few seconds, it has MBR formatting instead of GUID, could that be the problem perhaps ?

Comment: Please edit and post the output of `sudo systemd-analyze time`

Comment: The problem is not UEFI or anything systemd is doing. The firmware is waiting for something. You should be able to turn off the splash screen in firmware and see what it’s waiting for.

Comment: As already mentioned, the problem seems to be "BIOS" related and not operating system related. Did you try to boot to another system (possibly a live ISO)?

Comment: @lava The first link in your first comment has a typo in it. It should be `imgur.com` instead of `imgur.co`. The latter seems to a be risky click as it has an invalid SSL certificate that is shared with very "questionable" domains. Please [edit] your post instead and add the information to your question directly if it's relevant since the  comment cannot be edited anymore.

Answer (score 0):

the answer was easier than i thought, i forgot to reset the bios after switching from windows to ubuntu, went to the bios settings and loaded defaults, the bootup takes around 20 secs now.